# Quick Array Population

Tags: arrays, vb6

I have a application that will capture the screen and I want to write the captured information to an array, this takes AGES as the array ends up being +2million values. I am iterating and adding the values to the array, is there any way quicker (eg binary operations)? Should it be this slow? Why is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out why it was so slow, it was because I was using ReDim on every iteration of the loop - thanks for the help anyways

Martin

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `GetPixel`'ing the screen pixel by pixel, its the `GetPixel` call that's slow (it interrogates the display driver) not the (pre-dimensioned) array assignment.

You can instead use the `getdibits()` api which will copy the DC's colour info into a buffer in a single call.

[Here is a C++ example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659932/how-to-read-the-screen-pixels), but the methodology & call sequence is the same as for VB.