# Adding user-defined color in function putpixel(int x,int y,int color)

Tags: c++, bgi

I am trying to add orange color to my graphics code program. I am using putpixel(int x, int y, int color) function to add color. This function is not allowing to me to do so. Here's my code , Please help me to solve this problem

```cpp
 #include<iostream>
 #include<graphics.h>
 int main()
        {
        int gd=DETECT,gm;
        initgraph(&gd,&gm,NULL);
        int height,width;
        height=10;
        width=75;
        while(height!=43)
            {
            putpixel(width,height,12); //here i want to add orange color
            width++;
            if(width==225)
                {
                width=76;
                height++;
                }
            }
        getch();
        closegraph();
        }
```

I am trying to build an Indian flag. I am using GNU lib libgraph 1.0.2

Comment: `#include<graphics.h>` is not standard C++, and the name is so generic that I have no idea which 3rd-party library you might be talking about. On top of that, the code likely doesn't even compile, unless the mysterious `graphics.h` header file defines two global variables `height` and `width`.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: I would guess (https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs106b/cs106b.1126/materials/cppdoc/graphics.html)

Comment: But now the code has been edited with more info, and that guess was wrong.

Comment: It seems that `putpixel` is (https://www.cs.colorado.edu/~main/bgi/doc/putpixel.html).

Comment: Sorry, @ChristianHackl I am new on this forum. Anyway Thanks for helping

Comment: @NikhilPadole: Can you add to the question which graphics library you're using, or should we just close it?

Comment: @NikhilPadole: This isn't a forum. And I doubt you really understood what I was trying to say, because you still assume everyone knows about your mysterious `<graphics.h>`. Alf already made a wrong guess - why you don't you finally tell us **which library** you are using?

Comment: @ChristianHackl Thanks for clearing me I thought graphics.h is from standard c++ so I didn't post anything about the library. Sorry, once again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code looks like **BGI** (ancient Borland graphics interface for **MS-DOS**) which implies either emulation of **BGI** or real or emulated **MS-DOS**. Also it usually use only 16 color modes so you got only 16 indexes for colors from standard **EGA/VGA** palette. In case you use 256 colors you got standard **VGA** palette.

In this line:

```
putpixel(width,height,12);
```

the number 12 is the color used so you need to find which number is the orange you want. You can do that by rendering the whole palette like:

```
for (x=0;x<16<<2;x++)
 for (y=0;y<16;y++)
  putpixel(x,y,x>>2);
```

and count the index from the left starting with zero (do the 256 colors in more lines so you can still count the colors ...) You can also use this

- [VGA Color Palettes](http://www.fountainware.com/EXPL/vga_color_palettes.htm)

Taken image from above link:

[image: 16 colors]

the numbers are in hex so `12 = 0x0C` which is red-ish. If your output got similar color than you got the same palette ... If not that means you got different palette (may be Linux or WEB palette)

Here also the standard **VGA** 256 color palette from the same link:

[image: 256 colors]

If wanted color is not present you need to redefine palette which can be done by [accessing VGA I/O (reading palette)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19642738/2521214) but will not be possible under Windows or Linux without IO priviledge access. Possibly your gfx lib got some functions doing/emulating it....

Another way is to use [dithering](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36820654/2521214) so you take red and yellow and mix them (some pixels are red some yellow near by).

**PS** using put pixel is **soo slooow** you can render filled rectangles directly with **BGI** instead. It supports basic geometric shapes and more just see the **BGI** docs there are tons of them out there. I do not liked **BGI** at that time and did not use it at all as direct **VGA/VESA VRAM** access was way faster and better in any way. Using/learning it now is silly (unless you are forced to it by school). There are many alternatives see:

- [Graphics rendering in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21699076/2521214)

If you see the `gfxinit()` function in that link there is a routine to change the 256 color **VGA** palette.

Comment: ...Thank you for that detailed answer ..and I am forced by school to learn this things