# How can I print numbers on assembly in graphic mode? I want to print a changing number (variable that changes among the time) and not a string

Tags: assembly, graphics, x86, dosbox

I'm building a game in assembly and I want to print the score every time, how can I do that?
I made a variable named score but I don't know how to print it on the screen as a number

Comment: Convert to string first. Plenty of examples for that if you can't figure it out yourself.

Comment: You will need some fonts to convert the numbers to graphics.

Comment: see [Graphics mode in assembly 8086](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48664419/2521214) so you should convert your number value to a string and print as such ... example of that can be found in the `GLSL example of using it for printing` link (but not in asm) btw using BCD can help with this. Another option is to render bars instead of numbers like I did win the `What is the best way to move an object on the screen?` link. You should add info like what format is your number (int, float, fixed, binary, BCD, other) and your code for printing it so we can see where the problem is

Answer (score 0):

The easy way would be to either get or create some bitmap images, one for each digit. Create an array of those bitmaps. And then use a mod then divide loop to extract the digits in reverse order, Use the digit value to index the bitmap array.

Given that you are even asking the question I have to assume that you have basic blitting operations already.

Comment: [How do I print an integer in Assembly Level Programming without printf from the c library?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46301894) and [Displaying numbers with DOS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45904075) have examples of int->digit-string in reverse order, storing backwards from the end of a tmp buffer.  So there are good examples for that part of the problem.