# Is there any way by which I can select my own hex colors to draw graphics in TURBO C++?

Tags: c++, turbo-c++, bgi

By default we have access to only 16 color while using graphics.h header file.

Is there any way I can manually add or select colors with the help of their hex code in Turbo C++ to draw some text/graphics?

Comment: palette can be changed each color is programable usualy with 6 bits per channel so you got 262144 colors to chose from. If you want more than 16 colors use 256 color mode or the high/true color modes 15/16 bpp and 24/32 bpp but you would need VESA for those

Comment: I dig up the palette settings [Reading the RGB values of the console color palette](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19642738/2521214) for the 16 and 256 CGA/EGA/VGA color modes