# How to convert/make HBITMAP to string C++

Tags: c++, string, client-server, hbitmap

EDIT: connection - socket connection

I'm working on stuff that require me to send HBITMAP through the connection, as known the sending is sending strings.

How can I make HBITMAP to string to send OR is there any other way to transfer the HBITMAP?

Comment: What is "the connection" connecting. An `HBITMAP` is only valid in the process where it's created.

Comment: i guess you are trying to use sockets.you can convert the bitmap to device independent bits(DIB). Once you have that buffer you can just send it out through connection. After receiving the DIB's you can construct the image back.

Comment: @RCBrand but how do I convert HBITMAP to DIB?

Comment: This is [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659932/how-to-read-the-screen-pixels) for getting the screen bitmap into DIB. Possibly chk this out.